# How to check if tag exisits before adding the new one to database [ASP MVC]

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How I can check if the tag is exists in the database before adding a new one ?? also if the tag exists I don't want to duplicate it just link the tag id with the book id ..

Here is the book class :

```
 public partial class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int Book_id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string User_ID { get; set; }

    public string UrlSlug { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Book_name { get; set; }

    public int Edition { get; set; }

    public int Category_id { get; set; }

    public DateTime Publish_date { get; set; }

    public string Author_name { get; set; }

    public string Book_Image { get; set; }

    public string Download_Link { get; set; }

    public string pdf_file { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    public string Book_Description { get; set; }

    public int View_Count { set; get; }

    public virtual string TagsListing { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Tag class :

```
public class Tag
{
    public virtual int Id
    { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name
    { get; set; }

    public virtual string UrlSlug
    { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

My Create (New book controller):

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Book model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            if(model.TagsListing != null)
            {
                Collection<Tag> TagBooks = new Collection<Tag>();
                var s = model.TagsListing.ToString();
                string[] newTags = s.Split(',');

                foreach (var val in newTags)
                {

                    Tag iTag = new Tag
                    {
                        Name = val,
                        UrlSlug=val,

                    };
                    db.Tags.Add(iTag);
                    TagBooks.Add(iTag);
                }

                model.Tags = TagBooks;
            }



            db.Books.Add(model);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }




        return View(model);

    }
```

My Create View :

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <h4>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.TagsListing, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3"})</h4>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TagsListing, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "alert-info form-control",@id= "tags"} })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TagsListing, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
```

If that possible , please let me know and how to do that .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
Leaving this since it got the questioner started and was a bit easier for them to read. However, there are much more efficient ways to go about this as other answers show.

Be careful of performance since you're doing a string match. I'm also assuming you just want to be unique on the name. If not, just compare whatever columns you want in the FirstOrDefault statement.

All Tags:

```
foreach (var val in newTags)
{
    var iTag = db.Tags.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == val);
    if(iTag == null)
    {
      iTag = new Tag
      {
        Name = val,
        UrlSlug=val,
      };
      db.Tags.Add(iTag);
    }
    TagBooks.Add(iTag);
}
model.Tags = TagBooks;
db.Save();
```

Comment: thanks a lot , yes actually I'm looking for All Tags , if the tag name that comes from the view already exists , I want to : 1- don't add new one . 2- link the tag id with the book id . your answer is correct but still need to make a link btw the tag exists and the book

Comment: Changed to reflect what you need.

Comment: Thanks , I tried it and got this error :
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.<br/>

Line 156:                            model.Tags.Add(iTag);

Comment: Fixed a typo. Should have been db.Tags.Add(iTag)

Comment: No worries. Good luck!

Comment: Is that effect a lot on the server ?

Comment: Because actually this code for only 1 admin and inside the admin panel , maximum will be using for 15-30 times per a day , Any way thanks a lot for helping me with that ..

Comment: This works, but it's incredibly inefficient. You're issuing N queries, where N is the number of tags. You should select all the relevant tags from the database first, rather than one at a time.

Comment: I'm leaving it since it worked for them and got them started on the path. It can be made MUCH more efficient by using the methods @ChrisPratt provided.

Comment: Yes you are right , I think I should learn the NoSQL most the professional developers advise this type , but as a developer which is the best MongoDB or you interest something else , and thanks

Comment: NoSQL is no better or worse than SQL. It just has different use cases. Use it when it makes sense to, not just because you think it's "faster". In some scenarios it will be, in others traditional SQL will beat the pants off it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look up the tags from the database based on the posted values:

```
var tags = db.Tags.Where(m => newTags.Contains(m.Name)).ToList();
```

Then, you need to manually remove tags from the collection that were removed and add tags that were added:

```
// Remove deselected tags 
model.Tags.Where(t => !tags.Contains(t)).ToList()
    .ForEach(t => model.Tags.Remove(t));

// Add newly selected tags
tags.Where(t => !model.Tags.Contains(t)).ToList()
    .ForEach(t => model.Tags.Add(t));
```

**EDIT**

Since this is a create view, the book has no tags yet. I gave you the code you would need to modify an existing book, since that is the more complicated scenario worthy of a code sample. For a brand new book, you'd simply set the tags directly to the book's property, i.e. `model.Tags = tags`.

Comment: can you please add this code to my controller code and show to me a full answer , because when I tried your answer got a null exception , may I added this wrong or missed something .

Comment: Because Actually I got an Null exception when I used your answer , but I really like the code way you posted here , so please if you can show me how is your code work with my controller , and i'll mark it also as answer .. thanks